# Xrandr only found one provider (but I have two graphic adapters)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, xrandr

I've a pc with Ubuntu 16.04.1.

Yesterday, I've installed another graphic adapter to my pc to get more display outputs.

My first adapter is a nVidia GTX 770, and I have four displays attached: two on dvi outputs, one in hdmi output, and another in display port output.

With this four displays Ubuntus works correctly.

The new adapter is a nVidia GT 640, with others four outputs (two DVI, one HDMI and one VGA analog output).

Both adapters are detected:

```
andye@Trabajo:~$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 770] (rev a1)
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 [GeForce GT 640] (rev a1)
```

I've test the system with the nVidia 367.57 default Ubuntu 16.04 driver and with the newly 375.26 driver (downloaded from nvidia webpage and manually installed).

Nvidia-xconfig detect my two adapters and my five displays:

```
andye@Trabajo:~$ nvidia-xconfig --query-gpu-info
Number of GPUs: 2

GPU #0:
  Name      : GeForce GTX 770
  UUID      : GPU-55d902e3-ce32-7e35-fdb2-e8c66954808d
  PCI BusID : PCI:1:0:0

  Number of Display Devices: 4

  Display Device 0 (TV-0):
      EDID Name             : BenQ GL2460
      Minimum HorizSync     : 30.000 kHz
      Maximum HorizSync     : 83.000 kHz
      Minimum VertRefresh   : 50 Hz
      Maximum VertRefresh   : 76 Hz
      Maximum PixelClock    : 170.000 MHz
      Maximum Width         : 1920 pixels
      Maximum Height        : 1080 pixels
      Preferred Width       : 1920 pixels
      Preferred Height      : 1080 pixels
      Preferred VertRefresh : 60 Hz
      Physical Width        : 530 mm
      Physical Height       : 300 mm

  Display Device 1 (TV-1):
      EDID Name             : Samsung T24C300
      Minimum HorizSync     : 15.000 kHz
      Maximum HorizSync     : 81.000 kHz
      Minimum VertRefresh   : 24 Hz
      Maximum VertRefresh   : 75 Hz
      Maximum PixelClock    : 230.000 MHz
      Maximum Width         : 1920 pixels
      Maximum Height        : 1080 pixels
      Preferred Width       : 1920 pixels
      Preferred Height      : 1080 pixels
      Preferred VertRefresh : 60 Hz
      Physical Width        : 530 mm
      Physical Height       : 300 mm

  Display Device 2 (TV-2):
      EDID Name             : BenQ GL2250H
      Minimum HorizSync     : 30.000 kHz
      Maximum HorizSync     : 83.000 kHz
      Minimum VertRefresh   : 50 Hz
      Maximum VertRefresh   : 76 Hz
      Maximum PixelClock    : 210.000 MHz
      Maximum Width         : 1920 pixels
      Maximum Height        : 1080 pixels
      Preferred Width       : 1920 pixels
      Preferred Height      : 1080 pixels
      Preferred VertRefresh : 60 Hz
      Physical Width        : 480 mm
      Physical Height       : 270 mm

  Display Device 3 (TV-3):
      EDID Name             : BenQ G2400W
      Minimum HorizSync     : 31.000 kHz
      Maximum HorizSync     : 94.000 kHz
      Minimum VertRefresh   : 50 Hz
      Maximum VertRefresh   : 85 Hz
      Maximum PixelClock    : 193.250 MHz
      Maximum Width         : 1920 pixels
      Maximum Height        : 1200 pixels
      Preferred Width       : 1920 pixels
      Preferred Height      : 1200 pixels
      Preferred VertRefresh : 60 Hz
      Physical Width        : 520 mm
      Physical Height       : 320 mm


GPU #1:
  Name      : GeForce GT 640
  UUID      : GPU-9fdb4b0d-2fde-cdeb-16e8-356757267c57
  PCI BusID : PCI:7:0:0

  Number of Display Devices: 1

  Display Device 0 (TV-1):
      EDID Name             : LG Electronics LG TV
      Minimum HorizSync     : 30.000 kHz
      Maximum HorizSync     : 83.000 kHz
      Minimum VertRefresh   : 58 Hz
      Maximum VertRefresh   : 62 Hz
      Maximum PixelClock    : 160.000 MHz
      Maximum Width         : 1920 pixels
      Maximum Height        : 1080 pixels
      Preferred Width       : 1920 pixels
      Preferred Height      : 1080 pixels
      Preferred VertRefresh : 60 Hz
      Physical Width        : 1600 mm
      Physical Height       : 900 mm
```

But xrandr only detect one provider:

```
andye@Trabajo:~$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x279 cap: 0x1, Source Output crtcs: 4 outputs: 6 associated providers: 0 name:NVIDIA-0
```

If I try to add a new provider:

```
andye@Trabajo:~$ xrandr --setprovideroutputsource 1 0
Could not find provider with index 1
```

I haven't a xorg.conf file.

Although if I config the displays as separated screens into nVidia X Server Settings, activating Xinerama and saving a new xorg.conf, five displays work, but I get several compiz errors (I can't drag elements in the screen [the app into we are dragging close inmediately]) and this is not a solution for me.

The question is: why xrandr only detect the first adapter?

And, how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: xorg.conf is obsolete. It's normal you don't have one.

Comment: did you ever get this working OP?

Comment: I have the same issue https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335280/xrandr-cant-see-more-than-one-x-screen-with-dual-gpu-video-cards-and-4-monitors